# jQuery drop down menu show/hide with click

Tags: jquery

First of all, I check most of the answers related with this but I didn't find any answer that works for me.

I want the p tag to be shown/hidden on click. Currently works only with hover like this:

```
<aside> 

    <div> 
      <ul>
          <li class="asideMenu"> <a href="#">Click to Open 1 </a>
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p> 
        </li>
          <li class="asideMenu"><a href="#"> Click to Open 2 </a> 
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p>
        </li>

          <li class="asideMenu"><a href="#"> Click to open 3 </a>
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p>
        </li>
      </ul>    


    </div>

</aside>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('div ul li p').hide().removeClass('asideMenu');
$('div ul li').hover(
function () {
    $('p', this).stop().slideDown(500);
},
function() {
    $('p', this).stop().slideUp(500);
}
);
```

What I've try is to change the '.hover' to '.click', also to include the click just before the function like .('click', function... , but I didn't had any success.

Can you tell me how the make the exactly same effect that I have now, but on 'click', not on 'hover'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did one of the answers work you? If yes please mark as accepted else let us know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`on.click()` has only one function as parameter so you can use like so:

If you want always to show only the clicked element and hide the previous opened do like so, else see comment in code

```js
$('div ul li p').hide().removeClass('asideMenu');
$('div ul li').on('click', function() {
    $('.subAside').slideUp(); // remove this line to hide/show only on click
    $(this).children('.subAside').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside> 

    <div> 
      <ul>
          <li class="asideMenu"> <a href="#">Click to Open 1 </a>
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p> 
        </li>
          <li class="asideMenu"><a href="#"> Click to Open 2 </a> 
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p>
        </li>

          <li class="asideMenu"><a href="#"> Click to open 3 </a>
               <p class="subAside"> Uneasy barton seeing remark happen his has. Am possible offering at contempt mr distance stronger an. </p>
        </li>
      </ul>    


    </div>

</aside>
```